# Sort array elements alphabetically PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I know there has to be a way to do this, but my googling was to no avail. I am trying to take a recordset, create an array and sort the elements alphabetically.
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: please update your question with schema / data / expected results & attempt made

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution and answered the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you will need to use the `ORDER BY` clause in the `ARRAY_AGG` function.
Example:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(fullname ORDER BY lastname)
FROM ...
```

This will return an array with names sorted by last name.